# How to pass multiple parameters in WCF Rest Service?

Tags: c#, wcf, service

I'm developing WCF REST service in C#. It works fine for a single parameter. Now I need to extend it to support multiple parameters. Please help me on this issue.

Thanks in advance...

Use following declaration in interface:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
    RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
    UriTemplate = "login")]
resLogin Login(reqLogin rData, int floorId);
```

Answer (score 11):

Take a look at [UriTemplate parameters](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/egady/archive/2008/01/14/http-web-programming-with-wcf-3-5-creating-a-template-based-uri.aspx). You can use the QueryString or URL path to pass in the `floorId` parameter.

#### URI Path Parameter

```cs
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "login/floor/{floorId}")]
resLogin Login(reqLogin rData, int floorId);
```

#### QueryString Parameter

```cs
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "login?floorId={floorId}")]
resLogin Login(reqLogin rData, int floorId);
```

Comment: Thanks lot it works fine... If we want to pass two objects like resLogin Login(reqLogin rData, reqFloor floorObj); How do we accomplish this task...

Comment: @kasuntharanga - please post a new question and mark this one answered. SO isn't a discussion forum.

Answer (score 3):

**Add BodyStyle on OperationContract**

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
```