# Pass parameters to WCF REST from C#

Tags: c#, wcf, rest

I have to pass the parameters to the WCF service that i created. When i tried to pass it as a QueryString it throwed me "`404 Not found`".

//Code:

```
string Service = ""http://localhost:58092/Service1.svc/DataService/LoadAllColumnData?Id=1";
WebRequest wreq = WebRequest.Create(Service);

WebResponse wres = wreq.GetResponse();

DataContractSerializer coll = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(DataServiceProxy.GdColumns));                      
var arrProd = coll.ReadObject(wres.GetResponseStream());
```

//WCF Code:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IDataService
{             
     [OperationContract]
     [WebGet(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "LoadAllColumnData/{Id}")]
     IList<GdColumns> LoadAllColumnData(string Id);
}
```

How to do this?

Comment: what is your client? winform or wpf or silverlight?

Comment: Web applicaiton in MVC4 pattern.

Comment: Look at the answer for this SO post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9381633/how-to-pass-multiple-parameters-in-wcf-rest-service

Comment: Try calling it from your browser. Most probably the problem is not the parameter, but the rest of the URL. (Before your edit tt seemed you missed the "http://" and also the server name).

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar: I have used the http, since SO didn't accpet my post with http i just deleted. Now i have updated the question.

Comment: why dont you add it as service reference and create a proxy?

Comment: @Sajeetharan Because you can't do that for REST services.

Comment: @SanthoshKumar Still, try it from your browser.

Comment: @Sajeetharan: I have added as proxy. But to consume the REST service from C# i found this method. Source: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=728

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar: It works fine. I can see the result in XML format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your **string Service** you specify a querystring **LoadAllColumnData?Id=1**... but in your **UriTemplate = "LoadAllColumnData/{Id}"** you have no querystring... you have defined that the URL will hold the parameter.

Change your service url as follows and it should work...

```
string Service = ""http://localhost:58092/Service1.svc/DataService/LoadAllColumnData/1";
```

To use the querystring...

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
    UriTemplate = "LoadAllColumnData?Id={Id}")]
IList<GdColumns> LoadAllColumnData(string Id);
```

To use the URL...

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
    UriTemplate = "LoadAllColumnData/{Id}")]
IList<GdColumns> LoadAllColumnData(string Id);
```

Edit: Changed POST to GET as Derek pointed out.

Comment: Method attribute should be set as GET, not POST. GET is idempotent, POST is not. Nothing is being changed on the server via this method.